# Effective method for showing IUView based on didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app with 2 layers (at the moment); bottomlayer has a tableView, and I would like top layer to show different buttons/labels/etc based on tableView selection. Instinct to to hide/show layers based on didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but that would necessitate hiding/showing a lot of layers based on selection. I also imagine the storyboard would get quite messy as well :(

Is there a more reasonable/effective method for changing the UIView on the toplayer based on tableview selection?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through them all in a for-in loop kind of like this:

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) //change this to your container {
                if (view.tag == 14)
                    continue; 

/*Do Nothing, this is the golden view that stays on screen.  Maybe set it's frame or alpha, but don't hide it.
*/
                else
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 768, 1024)]; //set this to any value that puts the view offscreen or set alpha to 0

            }
        }
    }
```

it all depends on you setting their tags, which index is selected and which view you want to exclude.

Although, depending on the changes you want, or how many objects you have to change, this method may actually be more cumbersome.

Comment: No, not necessarily.  Say you want to have multiple view's up (not the best example, but hey!), then you would exclude multiple tags.  The index is just there to determine which cells was pressed.'

Comment: Do you have any recommended reading for setting up subviews? Still pretty fresh to objC. Thanks!

Comment: If you do have multiple objects (and I mean quite a few) that need animation or changes, contain them all within their own UIView's, than way, you cut down on code.  Also [UIView animateWithDuration:animations^{}]; is a really easy way to make your app seem professional and get rid of those jerky frame changes.

Comment: There aren't that many objects. Each view (corresponding to each row in tableview) is going to be really simple--maybe a few labels and buttons. I'm basically trying to mimic the Facebook app, which is a bastardization of the masterview/detailview setup.

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention master-detail view!  well, anyways, it's basically the same thing then. Encapsulate each group of objects in it's own view, then call frame changes on that.

Comment: Thank you so for all the help! Just realized theres a stupid complicating factor: I wrote a pan gesture (left/right) for only the top layer. Is there any way to attach UViews to the topLayer view (which has the pan gesture) so that I can retain the pan, and show/hide Views as desired? I guess the alternative is to rewrite the pan to accept a layer name, and just just switch views as needed....

Comment: You're probably going to need a rewrite.